# Keep a UIViewController active in background all the time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, whatsapp

I have multiple `UIViewControllers`. I need to `implement` something like `Audio chat` with text chat similar to `Whatsapp Messenger`.

I can move to `chat ViewController` from the `Audio chat ViewController` and vice versa. 
But when I start moving to other `ViewControllers` or in case I reach to the root `ViewController`(which is a `tabbed` `ViewController`) the audio `ViewController` gets completely inactive and becomes difficult to reach back to that viewcontroller.

Is there any way that I can keep the audio `ViewControllers` alive all the time in background and switch to it from any `ViewControllers` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to make an object of your audio view controller in Appdelegate. and whenever you need to move to this, you can call this through appdelegate.